# How to keep running a task even after the app is killed?

Tags: android, timer, background

I have  a requirement where I'm  supposed to implement a timer that is displayed in the notification and is supposed to work even after the app is killed.

I have tried using background services, foreground services,broadcast receivers, alarm manager and work manager. But none of them worked once the app was killed.

I have tried using the 'solution' provided as answers to so many stack overflow questions regarding this, but none of them worked.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: On which device you are trying to do this?

Comment: If by killing you mean swiping form recents it's gonna be near impossible since most (if not all) android system implementations will kill your app process and prevent any kind of auto-start unless your app is manually relaunched again.

Comment: is your service getting killed?

Comment: a foreground service should have worked.

Comment: see the developer option of the device you are testing on. Maybe `dont keep activities` is on or the `background process limit` is set to none or `kill app on back button` is turned on or something of that nature.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. Tried using foreground service again, and it WORKED!.
Thanks Pemba for the motivation to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, maybe it would be better to create a widget, that displays the data on desktop? Widgets are automatically updated every half hour, but you can update it more regularly with AlarmManager etc. With widget you will not have to worry if the app is killed at all. And it will start working again even after the restart or OS update.